# API to add properties to Azure Webapp Application settings

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have one web app running on a Azure appservice plan. The web app has a lot of settings defined in Application settings of the Web App. Now I want to replicate that web app with all its Application settings. I got the REST API to list down all the settings available for any web app (/api/settings). Although there is a POST call to add/update the settings , But it is not updating Application settings.

Is there any REST API to add/update the Application settings of Azure web app ?

Thanks,
Abhiram

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any REST API to add/update the Application settings of Azure web app ?

Yes, we could update the application setting with the following [Update Application Settings REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings)

```
Put https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{WebAppName}/config/appsettings?api-version=2016-08-01
```

Body

```
{
  "id": "subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{WebAppName}/config/appsettings",
  "name": "appsettings",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "location": "South Central US",
  "tags": {
    "hidden-related:/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{groupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/tomfreePlan": "empty"
  },
  "properties": {
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "6.9.1",
    "Test1": "testValue1" //Added value
  }
}
```

[image]

**Note:** we could use the following [List Application Settings REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listapplicationsettings) **post** way to list the appsetting body.

```
 Post https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription}/resourceGroups/CXP-{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{WebAppName}/config/appsettings/list?api-version=2016-08-01
```

Comment: This REST API needs Subscription ID and Resource group. Also it needs Azure account authentication. But I have only sites deployment credential, I have only control over the site not on the Azure account. Kudus API /api/settings says it can delete settings, but it is not able to

Comment: @user2768967 As you mentioned that if you want to update the Azure WebApp application settings, Azure account authentication is required. The Kudus API/api/settings just **kudu website**  config settings not the **webapp Application settings**. You may mistake the two apis.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is not. But have you considered scripting your Web App settings with an ARM template? This is exactly the kind of thing that ARM templates are intended for.

An example of the properties section of a Web App's ARM template that lets you script appSettings and connectionStrings is listed below:

```
"properties": {
    "name": "YourWebAppsName",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', YourAppServicePlanName)]",
    "siteConfig": {
        "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "someAppSettingKey",
              "value": "someAppSettingValue"
            },
            {
              "name": "someOtherAppSettingKey",
              "value": "someOtherAppSettingValue"
            }
        ],
        "connectionStrings": [
            {
              "name": "defautlConnection",
              "connectionString": "YourConnectionString",
              "type": "2"
            },
        ]
    }
```

When you deploy an ARM template, Azure will ensure that the target resource's settings match what's specified in your template.

Visual Studio has a project type for developing and deploying these. It's the Azure Resource Group project type located under the Cloud node in the project templates.

As an added bonus, you can check these ARM templates into source control alongside your code.