# Clearing Azure web app config settings from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to use Azure PowerShell to clear all application settings and connection strings on a web app's site config.  It doesn't seem like the API even supports this.

I've tried using:

`Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $siteName -AppSettings @{}`

But this throws an error because the dictionary is empty.

I've tried using this command:

`Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceName "$siteName/appsettings" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -Properties @{}`

But I get an error saying `<Error><Message>The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.</Message></Error>`

I've also tried this:

`Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceName "$siteName/appsettings" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -Action "Post" -Parameters @{}`

But again I get this error:

`Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Parameters'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try 
the command again.`

Is there another way of clearing all appsettings?

There used to be a way to retrieve the webapp using Get-AzureRmWebApp, edit it locally, and then post the object using Set-AzureRmWebApp, and in fact the help documentation still says there is a -WebApp parameter, but it no longer exists in the latest Azure PowerShell.

Comment: Have tried getting the resource to see what it looks like?  Then just sending an empty collection?

Comment: I test in my lab, null has value is not allowed to pass to -AppSettings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test in my lab, `-AppSettings` does not allow a null hash value. I suggest you could pass a value to it. It will delete all original app settings and create a new key pair.  Like below:

```
$appsettings=@{
    'test'="test"
}

Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $siteName -AppSettings $appsettings
```

Another solution you could use [Azure Cli 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_appsettings_delete) to delete appsettings. For example:

```
az webapp config appsettings delete -n shuicli -g shuiapp --setting-names test shui
```

Update:

You also could use [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings) to delete application settings.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/config/appsettings?api-version=2016-08-01
```

Comment: If the Azure CLI supports deleting app settings, and so does the portal, it would stand to reason that there is some API method that can be manually called to do so.  But I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere

Comment: @TrevorElliott Maybe you could check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749976/api-to-add-properties-to-azure-webapp-application-settings).

Comment: @TrevorElliott Using `az webapp config appsettings delete -n shuicli -g shuiapp --setting-names test --debug` you could see how cli to call API.

Comment: @TrevorElliott I suggest you could use Power Shell to call this API. Sorry, I am not very good at API, maybe you could ask a new question.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Here is the [result](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Walter-Shui/87d6f3c607ff4b786b9135a5872287cb/raw/a292251d3240d97f6cd0007ade3657d71e9feb20/result.txt) that cli calls API. Hope it helps.