# Remove App Settings During Azure App Service Deployment

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Deploying via Azure Release Pipeline - and in our [Deploy Azure App Service](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/README.md) step, we set *App Service's Application Settings* via the
[image: Application-and-Configuration-Settings-App-settings].

Our contingency if the deployment fails, is redeploy an old release (months old) to the same app-service.

However, we need to delete some of the *App Service's Application Settings* that were set.  Just removing these in the old release pipeline *does not* remove them from the App Service Configuration App Settings section.

Now we don't have the luxury of deleting these app-settings manually on the App Service Configuration.
So what is the recommended way to achieve this through the pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

> Remove App Settings During Azure App Service Deployment

You could use the [Azure CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureCLIV1/Readme.md) task in the pipeline to delete appsettings, like:

```
az webapp config appsettings delete --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --setting-names {setting-names}
```

Check the [az webapp config appsettings delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-appsettings-delete) for some more details.

On the other hard, you also could use API [Web Apps - Update Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings) to delete application settings.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/config/appsettings?api-version=2016-08-01
```

You can check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749976/api-to-add-properties-to-azure-webapp-application-settings/47764961#47764961) here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case I had to remove WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE from appsettings and removing it from portal manually by clicking Delete->Save was removing it initially , then hit refresh and the setting was back UP, but doing it from CLI (first command) removed it completly.

Comment: Just in case someone comes along to this, You can also do the same via the powershell module with Set-AzWebApp -AppSettings switch.